# What's the meaning of "rush everything in"?

Tags: word-meaning

From NPR:

> In fact, you're more relaxed because you don't have to worry and *rush everything in* on Saturday.

I know that "rush everything" means "hurry to do everything", but why does the sentence add a word "in" after it? Is the word superfluous?

Comment: It's because *rush in* is an idiom: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rush+in.

Comment: What was the story about? In a retail location, "rush everything in" might mean get everything into the store so it can be put on the shelves. On vacation, "rush everything in" might mean to go visit all the locations on your sightseeing list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rush Everything In**

In your example, I think "rush everything in" is a modification to the idiom "get everything in". To "get everything in" would mean to do everything you needed to do in the amount of time you had to do it in.

For example, if I had to go to three different stores to do my Christmas present shopping, and I only had Saturday to do it, I would say that "I got everything in" if I managed to get to all three stores on Saturday.

To "rush everything in" would mean to "get everything in" but only by rushing. In other words, you got to all three stores, but you had to rush to do it.

**Rush Everything**

You could also say, "In fact, you're more relaxed because you don't have to worry and *rush everything* on Saturday." (I removed the word "in".) This sentence would mean that you don't have to rush everything *in general* on Saturday. There's no longer an implication that you have a list of things to do, and you need to rush to do those things.